# Derived table with an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the TSQL below:

```
DECLARE @TestTable table (reference int identity, 
                          TestField varchar(10), 
                          primary key (reference))
INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES ('Ian')

select * from @TestTable as TestTable
INNER JOIN LiveTable on LiveTable.Reference=TestTable.Reference
```

Is it possible to create an index on `@Test.TestField`? The following [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767905/how-to-create-index-on-derived-tables) suggests it is not.  However, I read on another webpage that it is possible.

I know I could create a physical table instead (for @TestTable).  However, I want to see if I can do this with a derived table first.

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886050/sql-server-creating-an-index-on-a-table-variable

Comment: You can as detailed in @Pradeep's link. Alternately you can create an index on a temp table instead which will give you better performance: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/create-index-on-temp-table

Comment: @Tanner - Answer is Yes u can create index. Check the second answer in that link

Comment: @Tanner, thanks.  I did not realise that temp tables were only visible to the current session.  That answers my question.  If you want to post an answer then I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an index on a table variable as described in the top voted answer on this question:

### [SQL Server : Creating an index on a table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385085/57475)

**Sample syntax from that post:**

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE TABLE (
  [ID]   [INT] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Name] [NVARCHAR] (255) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name], [ID]) 
  )
```

Alternately, you may want to consider using a temp table, which will persist during the scope of the current operation, i.e. during execution of a stored procedure exactly like table variables. Temp tables will be structured and optimized just like regular tables, but they will be stored in `tempDb`, therefore they can be indexed in the same way as regular table.

Temp tables will generally offer better performance than table variables, but it's worth testing with your dataset.

More in depth details can be found here:

### [When should I use a table variable vs temporary table in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857789/when-should-i-use-a-table-variable-vs-temporary-table-in-sql-server)

You can see a sample of creating a temp table with an index from:

### [SQL Server Planet - Create Index on Temp Table](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/create-index-on-temp-table)

> One of the most valuable assets of a temp table (#temp) is the ability
>   to add either a clustered or non clustered index. Additionally, #temp
>   tables allow for the auto-generated statistics to be created against
>   them. This can help the optimizer when determining cardinality. Below
>   is an example of creating both a clustered and non-clustered index on
>   a temp table.

**Sample code from site:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID      INT,
    UserName    VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Users
(
    UserID,
    UserName
)   
SELECT 
     UserID     = u.UserID
    ,UserName   = u.UserName
FROM dbo.Users u

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Users_UserID ON #Users(UserID)

CREATE INDEX IDX_Users_UserName ON #Users(UserName)
```